# License error with android 4.4 emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-4.4-kitkat

I updated today the sdk to the new version and I've got a problem with the license. When my application starts with the new Google API lev. 19, I receive a "License has stopped" error. From logcat I can see this kind of error:

> 11-01 06:47:57.120: E/AndroidRuntime(991): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 11-01
>   06:47:57.120: E/AndroidRuntime(991): Process: com.android.vending,
>   PID: 991 11-01 06:47:57.120: E/AndroidRuntime(991):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: **Unable to instantiate application
>   com.android.vending.VendingApplication:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.android.vending.VendingApplication"** on path: DexPathList[[zip
>   file
>   "/system/app/LicenseChecker.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]]

Comment: Did you report this issue to http://b.android.com?