# Android emulator rotates but app doesn't redraw

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, autorotate

I've seen pictures of this elsewhere, but from some time back where the answer is generally "this is a known issue with Android 2.3"  I'm using 4.4, so that's definitely not the answer.

I have about the simplest program ever:  "Hello, Android".  When I launch the emulator, it load up in portrait mode.  Using Fn-Ctrl-F11 (Mac), the emulator rotates to landscape mode.  But the application and the phone controls do not redraw - the whole thing just looks sideways.

Here's the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.test.helloandroid"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="18"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.test.helloandroid.Hello"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

and the Activity XML file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context=".Hello" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm building with Eclipse, the ADT bundle build v22.3.0-887826, although I can't imagine that matters for something this trivial.

My emulator is for device Galaxy Nexus, Android 4.4 API level 19.  I've tried this with Hardware keyboard present marked and unmarked.  I found reference to a "keyboard lid support" setting which I haven't seen anywhere - this comment is from 3/12 & so may be outdated.

This is my first Android app, so I'm a complete novice at debugging in this environment.  TIA for any suggestions on what I'm missing.

EDIT:  Adding code for hello.java

```
package com.test.helloandroid;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class Hello extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hello);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.hello, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: when orientation changes activity is destroyed and recreated.

Comment: post code of `Hello.java`

Comment: Post your code of Hello.java

Comment: @MehulJoisar Thank you for the link - and for the Log and Toast suggestions.  I've updated my code to have the same log messages as your suggestion.  Interestingly, I get the OnCreate when first launching the app through Eclipse - but when I rotate the emulator, I get no Toast messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently,everything old is new again: [orientation change bug in 4.4](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61671)

"The more they overthink the plumbing, the easier it is to stop up the drain."

It's good to know that I've not missed something obvious; OTOH this is a pretty obvious FAIL on the part of google's quality assurance... did bill gates sneak in there while no one was looking?  Or are they greedy & trying to sell phones for testing by mucking up the emulators?  Looks like there's a device in my future.

**Edit :**

Reference : Answered by CommonsWare,the Framework Engineer of Android.

[Impossible to rotate the emulator with android 4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726285/impossible-to-rotate-the-emulator-with-android-4-4)

Answer (score 2):

If you are beginner,you should go through [this reference document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) to know about `Activity lifecycle`.

Here,I'm including few `Log` and `Toast` to make it easier to understand the process happens when you rotate the screen.

**Example:**

```
package com.test.helloandroid;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class Hello extends Activity {


private static final String TAG = "Hello";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hello);

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    Toast.makeText(this, "onCreate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.hello, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Log.d(TAG, "onResume");
    Toast.makeText(this, "onResume", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    Log.d(TAG, "onPause");
    Toast.makeText(this, "onPause", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


}
```

I hope it will be helpful !!

Comment: I was expecting that when the screen rotated I would see a second message appear, but that doesn't actually happen.  I've upvoted your answer because it's very helpful information, but unfortunately I am left with non-rotating content inside of a rotated emulator shell.