# onConfigurationChanged not getting called even with manifest config changes - Why?

Tags: android, manifest, screen-rotation, onconfigurationchanged

I know the question is awful, [done thousands of times](http://tinyurl.com/nyjuc6y) ; But seriously, I've been stuck for 4 hours trying to solve this. I came into every link from 2009 until today and all of them give the same solution which (**** knows why) is not applying into my case.

This is the activity inside my manifest:

```
<activity 
android:name="com.example.activities.CamerasActivity"
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
</activity>
```

I'm using SDKs 4.0 or higher:

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="16"
android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

And this is my class:

```
public class CamerasActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.cameras_activity);

        VideoView videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.action_cameras);
        videoView.setVideoPath("/storage/sdcard/teste.mp4");
        videoView.start();
    }

    //Still not working
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        if(newConfig.orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        {
            Log.d("System.out", "Welcome to Landscape Mode");
        }
        else if(newConfig.orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
        {
            Log.d("System.out", "Welcome to portrait mode");
        }
    }
}
```

When I run my app like this I can see in portrait mode, works fine. if I use `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` on my manifest, I can see forced in landscape mode. This means my layouts are fine but why exactly my `onConfigurationChanged` isn't getting called when I try to rotate the screen? What am I missing?

EDIT:

AVD Config:

[image]

Auto-Rotate enabled:
[image]

Video the way it is:
[image]
And no outputs on my logcat.

Comment: The `onConfigurationChanged` method is called when you physically rotated an Android device. Did you physically turn your device?

Comment: No, I thought I could see this move on the AVD - Didn't find any reference telling me that rotation only applies on a real device; I think you can post this as an answer.

Comment: To see it on the AVD, press **Ctrl+F11** to change / mimic screen orientation.

Comment: But I did use the Ctrl + F11 and still cant see the layout rotating...

Comment: Forgot to mention that you'll need to enable screen orientation first via the AVD's Setttings option, then press Ctrl+F11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onConfigurationChanged` method is called when you physically rotated an Android device. So, you need to rotate your device to see the method gets called.

Note: The onConfigurationChanged also gets called when you changed locale, etc. See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29) for more info.

Also, I would have these values for the `android:configChanges` directive:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|layoutDirection
```

Also, Issue [61671](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61671) might be related to the screen orientation problem described in this post. *As of April 2014, this defect / bug has not been resolved by Google.*

**WORKAROUND**

As stated in this SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726285/impossible-to-rotate-the-emulator-with-android-4-4), screen orientation might work if the device type is set as a **generic 7" tablet** instead of **Nexus 7**.

Comment: I cant find the settings option on AVD edit and I'm running a quick research to find it; could you edit your answer and post more details about this enable please? thus I can accept the answer

Comment: Inside the AVD is already enabled? did you mean outside on eclipse configs?

Comment: No, I mean inside the AVD. Post your AVD config. Strange that it cannot rotate with CTRL+F11 and screen rotation is enabled in the AVD!...

Comment: the layout direction didnt work; from where can I retrieve the avd config information? I mean, is there some sort of txt file where everything is up? cause Im looking at ddms perspective and I cant find...

Comment: No, just post a screen dump so I can see what you set for your AVD. Normally, I would have these options for an AVD: **RAM:256**, **VM Heap:64**, **Internal storage:200**, SD Card **Size:50**. And select **Hardware keyboard present** option.

Comment: From your AVD screenshot, change RAM first to 512 (See the error posted by Android in the screenshot?). Internal storage and SD Card don't need to be 1GB (1,024) - unless your app it's a few hundred megabytes. Also, try turning off the Emulation option to see if it help.

Comment: Without running your app, when you press Ctrl+F11, does your AVD screen rotate?

Comment: Now that you mentioned - No, it's not...I believe my settings layout should rotate with CTRL + F11 but it isn't...Browser also doesnt rotate...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726285/impossible-to-rotate-the-emulator-with-android-4-4  Found this and maybe its the cause

Comment: Issue [61671](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61671) is similar to your problem. I see the defect is still not completed by Google.

Comment: Yeah it is and I solved right now, thanks for not give up. Edit your answer please, speak about the bug and to change the run device to a generic tablet from 7" as suggested on the previous link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726285/impossible-to-rotate-the-emulator-with-android-4-4) I gave to you; I really would appreciate to give you those answer points, thank you very much!