# Android emulator rotates but not its contents

Tags: android, netbeans, android-virtual-device

I am following a tutorial to learn developing Android applications.

(I'm using Netbeans instead of Eclipse, I don't believe this has anything to do with my problem though).

The point is when I run the program and try to switch the AVD to landscape mode it actually rotates 90 degres but only the device, not the screen contents.

See the snapshot:

[image: landscape mode nok]

Comment: have you set your activity screenrotation to potrait in manifest? and also check if rotation option is enabled in the device or emulator

Comment: see if this topic helps: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7394447/3640637

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems related with using AVD for Android 4.4.2, as the following post denotes:

[Impossible to rotate the emulator with android 4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726285/impossible-to-rotate-the-emulator-with-android-4-4)

If I use instead an AVD for an older Android version as 4.1.2 the rotation works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

- Close the emulator instance.
- Edit the virtual device in the Android Virtual Device Manager.
- Select "Hardware keyboard present" and click "OK".
- Start the device again.

Should work now.