# auto rotate screen is not working android AVD

Tags: android, mobile, screen-rotation

I'm using android studio with AVD emulator but I'm wondering why Auto-rotate screen option is not working for the whole app.

[image]

Comment: Does it work if you open othter apps?

Comment: @Apurva No it didn't work for all apps

Comment: use genymotion instead :D

Comment: Try changing settings of your emulator if AVD lets you.

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira yes but I'm wondering why this is happening and only in my machine

Comment: what if you try changing your API Level? maybe, just maybe its API bug

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira I tried API Level 18, 19 and 21

Comment: pls see this. it may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726285/impossible-to-rotate-the-emulator-with-android-4-4

Answer (score 0):

The auto-rotate is not enabled on the virtual device by default. Pull down the notification bar and look for the Auto-rotate toggle and turn it on.